# How can I read the contents of a form within a DoGet() function?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am making a [map painter programme](https://matthewkeracher.github.io/Excel_DM.js/), that takes in X, Y and colour data from user input and stores in a [Google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lGlBfPSeCIjMOCyAUvtOiaUDU0f1J_l5FV_N0sRUY48/edit?usp=sharing).

The data is sent to the spreadsheet as a form, following this [solution](https://github.com/jamiewilson/form-to-google-sheets). When the form is submitted, it is sent as a new `row` to the `sheet` called `Global`. However, I have three sheets, `Global` `Local` and `Dungeon` and based on variables contained in the form data being submitted, I want the `doGet()` function in my appsheets to send the new row to the correct sheet.

Here is the appScript `DoGet()`:

```
  function doGet (e) {

  const lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
  lock.tryLock(10000)

  try {
    const doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))

    //++++++++++++++++++SEND TO GLOBAL++++++++++++++++++++++

    const Global = doc.getSheetByName("Global")
   

    const headers = Global.getRange(1, 1, 1, Global.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
    const nextRow = Global.getLastRow() + 1

    const newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
      //returns a new array, produced by applying a fucntion to every value in an array 
    return header === 'UniqueID' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
    })


    Global.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])

    //++++++++++++++++++++SEND TO LOCAL++++++++++++++++++++

  
  }
```

To clairfy, this code WORKS but I am struggling with how to tell it WHICH sheet (`Global` `Local` and `Dungeon`) to send the new row too. Right now, they are all going to Global. However if I have a field in my form that says either Global, Local or Dungeon, how can I have the appscript read this and act accordingly?

Conceptually, I need to refer to the part of the incoming form array that contains the name of the sheet, and then I can write the script to use that as the name of the sheet like this:

`const sheetname = doc.getSheetByName("Global/Local/Dungeon")`

Comment: If the form array contains the name of the sheet, you can pass in that name into the ```doc.getSheetByName(<name of form>)``` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Octavia, thankyou for the detailed proof. However, the answer to my question was this:

`const sheet = doc.getSheetByName(e.parameter[sheetName])`

I am able to refer to the incoming form data using the syntax `e.parameter[<column header>]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `google.script.run` to trigger functions in your script and pass values. See this overhauled script.

#### Sample Form:

[image: sample]

#### Script:

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
}

function processData(data) {
  const lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  lock.tryLock(10000);
  try {
    const doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ScriptProperties.getProperty('key'));
    const sheet = doc.getSheetByName(data['sheet']);

    const headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    const nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;

    const newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
      return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : data[header];
    });

    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow]);
  } catch(e) {    
  } finally {
    lock.releaseLock();
  }
}
```

#### Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="submit-to-google-sheet">
      <label for="sheet">Sheet:</label><br>
      <select id="sheet" name="sheet">
        <option value="Local">Local</option>
        <option value="Global">Global</option>
        <option value="Dungeon">Dungeon</option>
      </select>
      <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" required>
      <input name="firstName" type="text" placeholder="First Name">
      <input name="lastName" type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
      <button type="submit" onclick="google.script.run.processData(this.form);">Send</button>
    </form> 
  </body>
</html>
```

#### Input:

[image: input]

#### Output:

[image: output]

Comment: Updated my answer to using html forms now. Thanks @Rubén