# How can I send an entire array of form responses from HTML/Javascript instead of one at a time?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am making a [map painter programme](https://matthewkeracher.github.io/Excel_DM.js/), that takes in X, Y and colour data from user input and stores in a [Google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lGlBfPSeCIjMOCyAUvtOiaUDU0f1J_l5FV_N0sRUY48/edit?usp=sharing).

The data is sent to the spreadsheet as a form, following this [solution](https://github.com/jamiewilson/form-to-google-sheets). In my code, an array is filled with the X, Y and colour data, then when I hit a `Save All` button the form is filled through a loop and sent one after the other to my spreadsheet's `DoPost()` function.

**EDIT: Here is the loop that was requested by Octavia**

```
document.getElementById('paintButton').onclick = function () {

            console.log('')
            console.log('+++++++++ SAVING PAINT DATA ++++++++++')
            console.table(paintArray)
            console.log(paintArray.length + ' rows to save.')

            try{

            for (let i = 0; i < paintArray.length; i++) {
        
    //AUTOMATICALLY FILL EDITOR AS PAINTING
            
    uniqueID =  parentID +'-'+  paintArray[i].x +'-'+ paintArray[i].y +'-'+  paintArray[i].z 

    let saveMessage = 'Saving row ' + (i + 1) + '/' + paintArray.length + ': ' + '' +  uniqueID + ' at ' + paintArray[i].x + ',' + paintArray[i].y
    
    //document.getElementById('paintLabel').innerHTML = saveMessage
    
    console.log(saveMessage)


            document.getElementById('testLocation').value =  ''
            document.getElementById('testCategory').value = ''

            document.getElementById('testX').value = paintArray[i].x
            document.getElementById('testY').value = paintArray[i].y
            document.getElementById('testZ').value = paintArray[i].z

            document.getElementById('uniqueID').value = uniqueID
            document.getElementById('parentID').value = parentID

            document.getElementById('testFill').value = paintArray[i].fill
            document.getElementById('TextA').value = ''
            document.getElementById('TextB').value = ''
            document.getElementById('TextC').value = ''
            document.getElementById('TextD').value = ''
            document.getElementById('TextE').value = ''

             sleep(5000)
                  
            //AUTOMAGICALLY SUBMIT FORM DATA
            document.forms['mapData'].dispatchEvent(new Event('submit'));

       
  
}

console.log('+++++++++ PAINT DATA SAVED SUCCESS ++++++++++')

paintArray = []

alert("+++++++++ PAINT DATA SAVED SUCCESS ++++++++++")

}catch{

console.log('+++++++++ PAINT DATA SAVE FAILED ++++++++++')

}

}
```

So, what is happening is the form data is recieved and pasted to the nextRow in the [relevent spreadsheet.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71803364/how-can-i-read-the-contents-of-a-form-within-a-doget-function?noredirect=1#comment126888549_71803364) What happens in practice is I paint a bunch of squares, hit `Save All` and wait for the form to be filled, sent, and stored over and over again.

The *problem* I am having is that this process is slow, and error prone. I have a `sleep(5000)` in the loop to minimise errors but this increases the save time!

I have found [this solution](https://spreadsheet.dev/write-multiple-rows-to-google-sheets-using-apps-script) for the spreadsheet side of the problem, which basically pastes an array in bulk rather than row after row. The video shows that this is a much faster, slicker way to transfer lots of data. However, the data is being sent row after row from my [painter programme](https://matthewkeracher.github.io/Excel_DM.js/). What I am trying to figure out is whether there is any way to send the entire `paintArray` to my Google Sheet `doPost()`.

**I have some ideas.**

Firstly, I could keep the [painter programme](https://matthewkeracher.github.io/Excel_DM.js/) as it is and in the `doPost()` in my spreadsheet's appscript store the incoming entries into an array, and then once it is filled using the [method here](https://spreadsheet.dev/write-multiple-rows-to-google-sheets-using-apps-script); however, I am unsure how this would work if the `doPost()` is being called multiple times, and also I am unsure how to tell Google Sheets to enact the bulk paste of the array once all the forms have been submitted.

EDIT: Here is an ammended version of the `doPost()` that has the bulk paste code in it. But now I need a way to retrieve the bulk data.

```
    function doPost (e) {

  const lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
  lock.tryLock(10000)

  try {

    const doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
    const sheetName = doc.getSheetByName(e.parameter['sheetName'])
    const headers = sheetName.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheetName.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
    

    const nextRow = sheetName.getLastRow() + 1

    const newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
     
    return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
    
    })

  paintArray.push(newRow)
  
  sheetName.getRange(nextRow,1,paintArray.length, paintArray[0].length).setValues(paintArray);

    
  
} catch(e) {    
  } finally {
    lock.releaseLock();
  }
}
```

The second idea is to somehow change the [painter programme](https://matthewkeracher.github.io/Excel_DM.js/)'s method from sending individual forms through a loop to sending the `paintArray` as a whole array, which can then just be pasted by the `doPost()` function on the Google sheets end. However, I am struggling to find solutions to that online.

Comment: I would imagine it’s as easy as adding to the e.parameter object.  In your client e.parameter.table = [[1,”a”],[2,”b”],[3,”c”]];

Comment: Hi @TheWizEd, thankyou for your response. I think you know more about this than me. I have the `doPost()` set up to fill an array and paste it in bulk. My problem is that the data comes in as seperate form `submit` events.

Comment: `then when I hit a Save All button the form is filled through a loop and sent one after the other to my spreadsheet's DoPost() function.` Can you include how you loop those values?

Comment: @OctaviaSima I have done so.

Comment: You will have to collate all your input into an array while in the loop, and then after you exit the loop, pass all the values you collated to the doPost then have the doPost process the array

Comment: So, basically, submit one form where each field contains an array? So, instead of `fill: green`, it would be `fill: green, blue, blue, green?`

Comment: can you share a sheet where we can converse? I can't send you a message in stackoverflow chat.

Comment: Sure thing! https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fpuQjEkwV0kz5iNrkBiUwT8eGAMmV5h5lbld8whFi_c/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243937/discussion-between-octavia-sima-and-matthew-keracher).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that you'll collate your data first with a chosen delimiter (e.g. `,`) and then process it by splitting it inside the `doPost(e)`. This solution will modify your current code minimally.

#### html:

```
try {
  // initialize them to blank if needed
  array = [ 'testLocation', 'testCategory', 'testX', 'testY', 'testZ', 'uniqueID',
            'parentID', 'testFill', 'TextA', 'TextB', 'TextC', 'TextD', 'TextE' ];

  array.forEach(element => document.getElementById(element).value = '');
  
  for (let i = 0; i < paintArray.length; i++) {
    uniqueID = `${parentID}-${paintArray[i].x}-${paintArray[i].y}-${paintArray[i].z}`

    // append each item and have them delimited by a comma
    document.getElementById('testX').value += `${paintArray[i].x},`
    document.getElementById('testY').value += `${paintArray[i].y},`
    document.getElementById('testZ').value += `${paintArray[i].z},`
    document.getElementById('uniqueID').value += `${uniqueID},`
    document.getElementById('parentID').value += `${parentID},`
    document.getElementById('testFill').value = `${paintArray[i].fill},`
  }
  // submit them all at once
  document.forms['mapData'].dispatchEvent(new Event('submit'));
  paintArray = []
}
```

#### doPost(e):

```
...
const nextRow = sheetName.getLastRow() + 1;

// start of sample values 
headers = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']
// emulating an event object, assuming these are the values sent to doPost
var e = {};
e.parameter = { 'sheetName': 'Global', 
                'key1': 'a,b,c,d,e',
                'key2': '',
                'key3': '!,@,#,$,%'}
// end of sample values

// tokenize your values per header
var paintArray = headers.map(function (header) {
  return e.parameter[header].split(',');
});

console.log('before transpose:')
console.log(paintArray)
// transpose 2d data
paintArray = paintArray[0].map((_, colIndex) => paintArray.map(row => row[colIndex] || ''));
console.log('after transpose:')
console.log(paintArray)

// then proceed to use setValues
sheetName.getRange(nextRow, 1, paintArray.length, paintArray[0].length).setValues(paintArray);
...
```

#### Output (paintArray):

[image: output]

After getting the transposed array, you should now be able to write it by bulk into the spreadsheet.

#### Note:

- I only included the important parts of the code that shows how it's done. Feel free to combine this code into your existing one.

Comment: This is almost perfect, but I had some issues with defining headers in the `doPost()`, these should be only the columns that are to be split up. I am still having an issue with the other columns that are filled only once, for example, `sheetName`.

Comment: For the fields not to be split, you dont have to append them while in the loop. And include an additional if statement in your doPost to exclude them or give them static values instead.