# How can I keep an array filled outside of a function?

Tags: google-apps-script

This question is part of finding a solution to a [larger problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71876850/how-can-i-send-an-entire-array-of-form-responses-from-html-javascript-instead-of?noredirect=1#comment127015825_71876850). However, I  am wondering if there is a way to use a function to fill an Array. Based on the test code below, it seems arrays automatically empty after the function. I am looking to have a function that fills the array repeatedly, and another one that triggers to paste the resulting array.Note the `paintArray=[]` defined outside of the functions.

The `console` logs '1' for `fillArray()` but when I run `logArray()` right after it logs `[].`

```
const paintArray = []


function logArray(){

console.log(paintArray)


}

function fillArray(){

paintArray.push(1)
console.log(paintArray)

}
```

Comment: If you wish to save data between function calls then try Properties Service.  You can save any data that you can save as a string. Life JSON  `PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("mylabel",JSON.stringify(paintArray));`

Comment: In Google Apps Script global varies get initialized on every function call

Comment: I meant to say global variables get initialized on every function call.  My typing kind of suck s these days.

Comment: I did some research on the PropertiesService and you have been very helpful. Not found the exact solution yet though..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties) this way:

```
var scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();

function logArray(){
  Logger.log(scriptProp.getProperty("paintArray"))
}

function fillArray(){
  var obj = scriptProp.getProperty("paintArray")
  if(obj){ //check if paintArray Object exists
    var arr = JSON.parse(obj); //parse the value to array
    arr.push(1); //push value 1
    scriptProp.setProperty("paintArray", JSON.stringify(arr)) //set new value of arr to properties
  }else{
    scriptProp.setProperty("paintArray", "[1]"); //set initial value if paintArray object is undefined
  }
}
```

First run:

[image]

Second run:

[image]

Third run:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### Save and Retrieve Array from Properties Service

```
function saveArray(a) {
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("myarray",JSON.stringify(a));
}

function getArray() {
  return JSON.parse(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("myarray"));
}
```